# as it should be this code? Its a Oracle Procedure with if and else

Tags: oracle, if-statement, procedure

Please I try to make a procedure to copy from one table to another and then delete the contents of the previous with if and else sentences. (PERSONA1 and PERSONA1_BKP are created)

```
create or replace procedure TRASLADO(DNI VARCHAR2)
as
v_DNI varchar2(8);
v_GP char(6);
v_PRIMER varchar2(40);
v_SEGUNDO varchar2(40);
v_PRENOM varchar2(40);
v_GENERO char(1);
v_FECHA DATE;

begin

      SELECT NU_DNI, GP_VOTACION, AP_PRIMER, AP_SEGUNDO, PRENOM_INSCRITO, DE_GENERO, FE_INSCRIPCION
      INTO v_DNI, v_GP, v_PRIMER, v_SEGUNDO, v_PRENOM, v_GENERO, v_FECHA /*se usa into para que la variable pueda usar lo que se le envia*/ 
      FROM PERSONA1
      WHERE NU_DNI=DNI;
      IF (NU_DNI=DNI)
      BEGIN
      insert into PERSONA1_BKP values(v_DNI, v_GP, v_PRIMER, v_SEGUNDO, v_PRENOM, v_GENERO, v_FECHA, SYSDATE);
      delete from PERSONA1 where DNI LIKE NU_DNI;
      END
      ELSE 
      BEGIN
      dbms_output.put_line('EL DNI NO EXISTE');
      END


end TRASLADO;
```

Comment: What is your question / issue / error ?

Comment: What is your issue  ? are you getting any error or how its not working as you expecting ?

Comment: Use correct `IF` statement: `IF condition THEN ... ELSE  ... END IF;`

Answer (score 0):

```
begin
   execute immediate 'drop table table PERSONA1_BKP';
   execute immediate 'create table PERSONA1_BKP as select * from PERSONA1';
   execute immediate 'truncte table PERSONA1';
end;
```

V2:  (using if / else statements)

```
begin
   if false then
     null;
   else
     execute immediate 'drop table table PERSONA1_BKP';
     execute immediate 'create table PERSONA1_BKP as select c1 cn1, c2 cn2 from PERSONA1';
     execute immediate 'truncte table PERSONA1';
   end if;
end;
```

Comment: right.. also he wants to use if statements, i'll make v2.